# How to get scheduled big query display name in failure alert notification in Slack channel?

Tags: google-bigquery, alert, scheduling

I have created an alerting policy to receive failure alert for scheduled big query on slack channel and it is working fine. But I am not able to include Display name of scheduled big query in that alert policy documentation, so that it will come in slack alert.
I have used below configuration in alert policy.

protoPayload.serviceName="bigquery.googleapis.com" protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.insert" protoPayload.resourceName="projects/testproject/jobs" protoPayload.serviceData.jobInsertRequest.resource.jobConfiguration.labels.data_source_id="scheduled_query" severity=ERROR

Comment: were you able to find answer to this? I am also trying to do something similar to this.

Comment: No, I am not able to find answer to this yet.